# Blazor in Angular like selecting content

Tags: angularjs, blazor, blazor-client-side

Angular Example

**profile-contact.component.html**

```
<!-- Media -->
<gx-media-icon-card class="mb-5" label="Mail">
    <gx-icon name="mail" size="xl" class="mr-5" icon></gx-icon>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" text>{{contactDetail.email}}</a>
</gx-media-icon-card>
<!-- /media -->

<!-- Media -->
<gx-media-icon-card class="mb-5" label="Web Page">
    <gx-icon name="link" size="xl" class="mr-5" icon></gx-icon>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" text>{{contactDetail.website}}</a>
</gx-media-icon-card>
<!-- /media -->

<!-- Media -->
<gx-media-icon-card label="Phone">
    <gx-icon name="phone-o" size="xl" class="mr-5" icon></gx-icon>
    <span class="h5" text>{{contactDetail.mobile}}</span>
</gx-media-icon-card>
<!-- /media -->
```

**gx-media-icon-card.component.html**

```
<ng-content select=[icon]></ng-content>

<!-- Media Body -->
<div class="media-body">
    <span class="d-block text-light-gray f-12 mb-1">{{label}}</span>
    <ng-content select=[text]></ng-content>
</div>
<!-- /media body -->
```

As you can see, angular can be positioned wherever it wants by saying `select=[icon]` and `select=[text]`. In this case, what kind of path should I follow in my Blazor?

Answer (score 0):

You use `RenderFragment` type property for that. Your example will be something like this:

MediaIconCard.razor

```
@Icon

<div class="media-body">
    <span class="d-block text-light-gray f-12 mb-1">@Label</span>
    @Text
<div>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Icon { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Text { get; set; }
}
```

And ProfileContact.razor

```
<MediaIconCard>
    <Icon>
        <i class="fa fa-at></i>
    </Icon>
    <Text>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)">@ContactDetail.Email</a>
    </Text>
</MediaIconCard>

<MediaIconCard>
    <Icon>
        <i class="fa fa-link></i>
    </Icon>
    <Text>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)">@ContactDetail.Website</a>
    </Text>
</MediaIconCard>

<MediaIconCard>
    <Icon>
        <i class="fa fa-mobile></i>
    </Icon>
    <Text>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)">@ContactDetail.Mobile</a>
    </Text>
</MediaIconCard>
```